# On the relation of the expected squared norm of a random vector with its dimensionality

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,
\ldots,x_n)^\top\in\Bbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with mean $\mathbf{\bar{x}}=(\bar{x}_1,
\ldots,\bar{x}_n)^\top\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$, where $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ denotes the space of symmetric positive definite $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb{R}$.

I'm interested to prove (or disprove) that the expected value of $\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2$ is linear to $\mathbf{x}$'s dimensionality $n$, i.e., $\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2 = \lambda\cdot n$, where $\lambda>0$.

What I have so far is as follows:
$$
\Bbb{E}\left[\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2\right]
=
\Bbb{E}\left[\mathbf{x}^\top\mathbf{x}\right]
=
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Bbb{V}\left[x_i\right] 
+
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\Bbb{E}\left[ x_i \right]\right)^2
=
tr(\Sigma) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\Bbb{E}\left[ x_i \right]\right)^2.
$$

Now, if $\Sigma=\sigma^2I_n$ and $\bar{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{0}$, we have that
$$
\Bbb{E}\left[\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2\right]
=
tr(\Sigma) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\Bbb{E}\left[ x_i \right]\right)^2
=
n\cdot\sigma^2 + 0,
$$
which is what I want. But what if $\Sigma$ is not a multiple of the identity matrix? In other words, how does the trace of an $n\times n$ matrix relate to $n$?

Another approach would be to "standarize" the random vector $\mathbf{x}$, i.e., to create a new random vector $\mathbf{y}=C(\mathbf{x}-\bar{\mathbf{x}})$, where $C = B^{-1}$ and $B$ such that $\Sigma_x = BB^\top$. Then could we work with $\mathbf{y}$ instead of $\mathbf{x}$? In such a case, it would be $\Bbb{E}\left[\Vert\mathbf{y}\Vert^2\right]=n$. What do you think?

Comment: There is something a little annoying: you assume $\Sigma$ is given, but then $n$ is implied. What if $n$ varies? Then $\Sigma$ can't be the same, and you already found that $\Bbb{E}\left[\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2\right]$ depends on $\Sigma$. Thus your $\lambda$ must depend on $\Sigma$. But then, it could also depend on $n$ (which, as already explained, is *implied* by $\Sigma$). I don't see what you really expect. To find anything relevant, you have to work with a sequence of covaraince matrices of increasing order (like $\sigma^2I_n$, as you did).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you for your comment. I am not sure I understand your objections, though. What I would like to show is that the expected squared norm of $\mathbf{x}$ is proportional to the dimensionality of the space it belongs to (i.e., $\Bbb{R}^n$, thus proportional to $n$). I think that this holds in the case of zero mean and "isotropic" covariance matrix (i.e., $\Sigma=\sigma I_n$), but what about the general case? Apologies if I didn't get you point yet. Thanks again.

Comment: My point is, for instance if you take $\Sigma_{2n}=\sigma_1I_{2n}$ and $\Sigma_{2n+1}=\sigma_2I_{2n+1}$, then it fails. And it's not even the most general case. You have chosen a very specific sequence of covariance matrices, that's why proportionality holds.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My answer focuses on the part of $tr(\Sigma)$.
Since covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is symmetric, $\Sigma$ can be diagonalized as

$$
\Sigma = U^{-1}DU
$$
with an orthogonal matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D$.
From the property of trace,
$$
tr(\Sigma) = tr(U^{-1}DU) = tr(DUU^{-1}) = tr(D).
$$

Importantly, the (diagonal) elements of $D$ correspond to the eigenvalues of $D$, such that

$$
D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0  \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_{n-1} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_n
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and thus
$$
tr(\Sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i .
$$
So my understanding is:

- there is no direct connection between $\mathop{\mathbb{E}} [\Vert x \Vert^2] $ and the dimensionality of $x$.
- but if a set of $x$ is highly biased in some directions, the variance is higher in those directions and $\lambda$s bocomes larger, possibly resulting in a larger $\mathop{\mathbb{E}} [\Vert x \Vert^2] $.